# Swift - How can insert cell at tableView top keep offset and scroll inertia

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I use the following code to update my tableView

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    //Load more cell
    if tableView.contentOffset.y < 100 {
        let beforeTableViewContentHeight = tableView.contentSize.height
        let beforeTableViewOffset = tableView.contentOffset.y
        let moreDataArray = getAllMessages()

        for message in moreDataArray.reversed() {
            dataArray.insert(message, at: 0)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.tableView.layer.layoutIfNeeded()
            let insertCellHeight = beforeTableViewOffset + (self.tableView.contentSize.height - beforeTableViewContentHeight)
            let newOffSet = CGPoint(x: 0, y: insertCellHeight)
            self.tableView.setContentOffset(newOffSet, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

But when insert cell and reloadData(), scroll inertia will stop.

How can like whatsapp insert cell to top keep offset and scroll inertia.

[This is example](https://youtu.be/0S17mM--IqE)

In first 5 seconds, the table is short, when i fast scroll up and finger out(Like android scroll status scroll_state_fling), more content insert on top, at the same time can keep offset and scroll inertia, that so amazing, How can i do that?

Comment: change `self.tableView.setContentOffset(newOffSet, animated: false)` to `self.tableView.contentOffset = newOffSet`

Comment: Thx for reply, i try it but seem no difference, scrolling inertia still be stop.

Answer (score 0):

In order to maintain the inertia, you need to make sure that loading and reloading of the data are being called once. You have to put one boolean variable to stop load more being triggered more than once, like

```
var isLoadMore = true
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        //Load more cell
        if tableView.contentOffset.y < 100, self.isLoadMore {
            self.isLoadMore = false
            let beforeTableViewContentHeight = tableView.contentSize.height
            let beforeTableViewOffset = tableView.contentOffset.y
            let moreDataArray = getAllMessages()

            for message in moreDataArray.reversed() {
                dataArray.insert(message, at: 0)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.tableView.layer.layoutIfNeeded()
                let insertCellHeight = beforeTableViewOffset + (self.tableView.contentSize.height - beforeTableViewContentHeight)
                let newOffSet = CGPoint(x: 0, y: insertCellHeight)
                self.tableView.contentOffset = newOffSet
                self.isLoadMore = true
            }
        }
  }
```

I found that best place to introduce the load more featured with the tableView is `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method. In this method, you can check against the indexPath instead of `contentOffSet`.

Comment: Thx for reply, I try it, but regardless use 'willDisplay' or 'scrollViewDidScroll' the scroll inertia still stop, so vexed.

Comment: I added isLoadMore, it still so

Comment: Checkout the code at https://github.com/kaushaldeo/CodeSnippets/blob/master/LoadMoreWithInertia which works perfectly.

Comment: I copy and paste the solution to a new project to test, no any content display on tebleview, Should i missing anything on implement the code?